# Displaying list of data from different table in MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a basic MVC application with CRUD. I have 2 tables Project and Proposer with one to may relationship.

When user clicks on Details link it details information about the Proposer but insted I would like to display all the projects proposed by that proposer.

Here is my current Details method

```
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Proposer proposer = db.Proposers.Find(id);
        // I got the ID here now how do i compare with the projects?
        if (proposer == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(proposer);
    }
```

Now how do i display the projects for that proposer?

Comment: You can access All Project proposed by proposer by just doing `proposer.Projects` assuming you have proper relationship and navigation property.

Comment: Hi Bikal, Thanks for your help. I am still getting this error: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<TechProject.Models.Project>' to 'int'. Do you know what does it mean? And I have a one to many relationship between Proposer and Project.

Comment: @HarshPanchal Could you please show the code for model and view.

Comment: Hi @BikalBhattaria, Thanks for your reply. Here is my model:  public class Proposer
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ProposerName { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string ProposerEmail { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Url)]
        public string WebAddress { get; set; }
 public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Here is my view:  TechProject.Models.Proposer
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}
<h2>Details</h2>
<div>
    <h4>Proposer</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProposerName)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            //model.name
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProposerEmail)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            //model.proposeremail
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>

Comment: @Manoz It's still not displaying the projects belongs to that proposer. It's only displaying the details of the proposer.

Comment: @Manoz Thank you so much for your help. It's showing the projects list now. the problem was in my view where I have  to strongly type the view.

Comment: @HarshPanchal, If my answer helped you; mark it as helped. Previously I deleted it thinking of no use of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Linq
```

**change**

`db.Proposers.Find(id)`

**to**

```
var proposer =  db.Proposers.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.ID==id.Value);
```

This will return only record if this is unique in the table.

To return List you may do-

```
var proposer =  db.Proposers.Where(p=>p.ColumnID==id.Value).ToList();

return View(proposer)
```

You are supposed to pass list type object and that is correct in your case.

But In the view you acquire single entity.

**Pass this to return View**

```
    var proposer =  db.Proposers.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.ID==id.Value);//not the list type
    return View(proposer);
```

**Note-** Don't pass list type object when you have single entity of your object. You were trying to pass list type object whereas your model in the view is asking for a single entity.

Comment: Hi Manoz, Thanks for your reply. I tried with both but I am still getting this error. The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TechProject.Models.Proposer]'. I am not sure where it went wrong. I have generated new view as well for ProposerControler.Details method using Project Model. Am I doing right? But, I need to display the list of Projects for that proposer.

Comment: @HarshPanchal, You should use list type model in your view. Were  you not using it as list type?

Comment: No, I generated the view automatically. I haven't strongly typed. Could you please explain me how do I do that in view?

Comment: You mean?  var project = db.Projects.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == id.Value); return View(project);

Answer (score 0):

here it is problem in your view instead of this

```
@model yourappname.Models.Proposers
```

try this

```
@model List<yourappname.Models.Proposers>
```

because you are sending list and view you are getting single so also change that into list

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have added the list in my view. But, how do I access all the projects that belongs to a proposer?

Comment: make a public List<projects> projects {get; set;} in proposers model

Comment: I have used ICollection Is this wrong? public class Proposer
    {   public int ID { get; set; }
        public string ProposerName { get; set; }
        public string ProposerEmail { get; set; }
       public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    }  My Project model 'code'  public class Project{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string ProjectTitle { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
         [ForeignKey("Proposer")]
        public int ProposerID { get; set; }
        public virtual Proposer Proposer { get; set; }}

Comment: this is ok but but with virtual Icollection<Project> also use List<Project> because virtual is navigation property

Comment: Thanks for your all help. It's displaying all the projects now. The problem was in my view where I have link it with my few codes in controller.

Comment: As in my ans i told you have to get list instead of getting single model you can see above i changed code for your view